# Find list of N increasing values that add up to S given start value V

Tags: summation

1. I have a list of `N` items
2. The price of the 1st item in the list is `valueA`
3. I want the price to gradually increase from one item to the next one in the list.
4. If I sell all N items, I want my total earnings to be `T`.
5. I'm looking for the price each item should have (Currently I only know the price of the 1st one: `valueA`).

In other words, the following must be true:

```
(valueA + valueB + valueC +  .... + valueN) === T
```

and:

```
valueA < valueB < valueC < .... < valueN
```

I'm looking for a formula that will return these values `[valueA, valueB, valueC,  ....valueN]`

To give you a more or less simple example:

If **`valueA`** is `1`, **`N`** is `7` and **`targetSum`** is `25`, then one valid result could be:

```
[1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 5.5, 6.5]
```

or:

```
[1, 2, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 5, 7]
```

and many other combinations.. but I'm looking for the single most *linear* (in terms of increments) solution if that makes sense.

Is what I'm looking for impossible due to the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)?

If it's actually possible, given that I am not a mathematician and I don't understand mathematical formulas, I would appreciate it if you could *also* include a more "verbose" answer as in (random example):

```
(add/divide/multiple currently known values) and their result X is your 2nd price
now knowing X move on to the 3rd price and repeat the above etc...
```

Comment: Have you looked into a modified Greedy Algorithm?

Comment: No but I will now, thanks (!)

Comment: You can do this mathematically see: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwqjd953/1/)

Comment: This works perfectly @pilchard and it is indeed "linear". I added this extra line in the loop to make sure it gets to the correct `targetSum` in the end: https://jsfiddle.net/f0xj69na/1

Comment: Yes, a check at the end is a good idea especially given floating point math, or rounding to meaningful decimals. Glad it helped.

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer along with some helpful information as to what exactly the logic behind this formula is when you get a chance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that :

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = T$
- $0 < x_1 < T$
- There exists $k > 0$ such that 
  for all $m \in \{1,2,\cdots,n-1\}, ~x_{m+1} - x_m = k.$

If this is possible, then this will automatically satisfy the desired constraints.

So, it is simply a matter of solving for $k$.

The only way that this is possible is if $(n \times x_1) < T.$  
So, without loss of generality, assume that this is true.

You have that : 
$x_2 = x_1 + k.$ 
$x_3 = x_2 + k = x_1 + 2k.$ 
$x_4 = x_3 + k = x_1 + 3k.$ 
$\cdots$ 
$x_{n} = x_n + k = x_1 + (n-1)k.$

Therefore

$$T = x_1 + \cdots + x_n = (n \times x_1) + [k + 2k + \cdots + (n-1)k]$$

$$= (n \times x_1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} ik$$

$$= (n \times x_1) + \left(k \times \frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}\right).$$

The above equality will be satisfied if and only if $k$ is chosen so that

$$T - nx_1 = \frac{kn(n-1)}{2} \iff \frac{2(T - nx_1)}{n(n-1)} = k.$$